# Can't change background-image size via css in flask

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flask, background-image

I have a css file in my static folder, where I set a background-image for a site of my Flask App. However, no matter what I try, it doesn't apply any "size" parameters I insert. It always stays the same! `background-size` is ignored by the browser. It always looks the same.

In Chrome the image is always too big. In firefox it works correctly. When I press ctrl + plus/minus, the background image gets bigger/smaller in chrome, whereas in firefox it stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

I insert the style.css file in my html-template like that: `<link rel="stylesheet" href=" {{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }} ">`

my style.css-file:

```
body {
    background-image: url("myPicture.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The url in the `.css` file is not pointing towards a valid image file url. Assuming the file is stored in the static folder of your app, you can try:

```
background-image: url("static/myPicture.jpg");
```

I'm not sure where the current background image is coming from, we simply don't have enough info to properly debug.

Comment: I have the picture located next to the .css file in my static-folder!

Comment: I've tried using `background-image: url("static/myPicture.jpg");
` and `background-image: url("/static/myPicture.jpg");` and `background-image: url("<full/path>/static/myPicture.jpg");`. It shows effect on firefox. On chrome, however, I don't get any changes regarding the size of the background-image...

Comment: I have observed,  that the problems arise (both on firefox and chrome), when I put the Browser Window in full size. When I shrink the Browser Window, the background-image looks the it is supposed to.